# Extract mismatch by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 |
| AB | 1 | 3 |
| CD | 2 | 4 |
| CD | 2 | 3 |

I would like to compare row within each ID.
For each column with difference add in the mismatch referred to the column.

Output:

| ID | col1 | col2 | mismatch_extract_col1 | mismatch_extract_col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 1 | 3 | Na | Na |
| AB | 1 | 3 | Na | Na |
| CD | 2 | 4 | Na | 4:3 |
| CD | 2 | 3 | Na | 4:3 |

Comment: What is `4:3`? A character string `"4:3"` or a list of vectors `c(4, 3)`?

Comment: A character string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct() == 1` to know if there is a mismatch in each column by `ID` groups.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(col1:col2, ~ if_else(n_distinct(.x) == 1, NA, toString(.x)),
                .names = "mismatch_extract_{.col}"),
         .by = ID)

# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#   ID     col1  col2 mismatch_extract_col1 mismatch_extract_col2
#   <chr> <int> <int> <lgl>                 <chr>                
# 1 AB        1     3 NA                    NA                   
# 2 AB        1     3 NA                    NA                   
# 3 CD        2     4 NA                    4, 3                 
# 4 CD        2     3 NA                    4, 3
```